# Does Orchard CMS set a cookie when user is authenticated?

Tags: orchardcms

Once a user has been authenticated via Orchard CMS is a cookie set on the users's system? If so can I read it from the same domain?

I would like to use Orchard to authenticate a user before re-directing them to another location on our domain and I am trying to determine how the web app they are redirected to can determine if they have been authenticated before allowing them access.

Answer (score 0):

Orchard uses ASP.NET Forms Authentication mechanism so yes, there is such cookie set. By default this cookie is only visible to the subdomain that sent it, but you can easily change this behavior by setting domain explicitly in web.config file.

Comment: Thanks @Piotr! Could I extend Orchard to set my own cookie? Perhaps one specifically for the web app I want to forward authenticated user to?

Comment: Is there a way to check this cookie via jQuery? It appears as though the cookie is set as HTTP Only.

Answer (score -1):

Yes Orchard does uses Forms Authentication.

You can find the code for it in (Solution Control of Visual Studio)

Orchard.Framework => Security => Providers => FormsAuthenticationService

You can find how orchard does at the above mentioned path in the void methods of SignIn and SignOut